# Is there code related changes will comes when upgrade to fastlink 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: yodlee

is There any code related changes like getting memsiteid after adding account and all api's call related code when i apgrade my application to fastlink 2.0

Answer (score 0):

There is no changes to the APIs, all the APIs will work as it is.
The changes in FL 2.0 is from UI perspective and also the way you access it. Accessing FL 2.0 is no more dependent on Oauth.

Comment: means we don't need to create Oauth_Signature and etc to access fast link